# GPU function in Blender

Tags: gpu

I'm currently building a pc for sole purpose of blender. I was just curious as to what the function of the gpu is in blender So I can decide which GPU to buy. I have a rough understanding of CPU function but not sure GPU other than it can be used to render

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60797 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPU can be used for faster viewport display, more vertices count. A PC with a powerful GPU can handle Millions of vertices and faces, but Consumer Notebooks cannot be used to get that performance. GPU can also take over some functions of CPU in rendering, it can handle Volumes , Procedural Textures better than CPU, specifically GTX is mostly used for Realtime, and is famous among gamers, and RTX is for  has specific algorithms for raytracing, (useful for Cycles in blender). When you set Your GPU in the CUDA section in Preferences , you let the GPU do most of the calculations in blender(after setting to GPU Compute in Render settings) and it can do somethings faster than your CPU.

Comment: GPU calculations are not "better" in general, it's just faster in *some* cases.

Comment: overall you get the idea its better for like almost everything complex and can handle big amount of work which is common in CG @brockmann

Comment: How many gb would you consider to be a ‘powerful’ gpu

Comment: I would say that somewhere about 8 gb should be good @user107904

Comment: In other words: GPU's *can't handle large scenes* due to RAM limitations... The reason why production renderers like renderman, mantra, arnold or 3d light are *still not* entirely gpu based. Without going to much into technical details, calculations are mostly done in 16bit in order to save some space on the card (which is not that precise as it could be). So again, it's not "better" in general, it depends on what you do, as always.

Comment: @user107904 if this answer has benefited you , you can click the tick mark bellow question voting system to declare this a correct answer

Comment: Thank you for your help