What would be recommended PC specs for creating?
I want to upgrade my PC, I don't know what the PC specs should be so I can make bigger projects and smoother models. Anyone have any PC specs recommendations? (I couldn't find any good tags for this post)

You couldn't find good tags because these questions are off-topic here. This site is about getting help with the use of Blender, not for hardware recommendations. In general, always buy the best hardware you can afford.

Read right through https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/277104/what-computer-should-i-buy-for-blender-how-do-i-choose-hardware.
